# java.lang.NullPointerException when SpriteBatch.end() occurs

Tags: java, libgdx

**Update:** Solution at the bottom of this post.

I'm having a problem in which when my game is run, the screen is just black and crashed a couple seconds later. I declare a new SpriteBatch in my main `Game` class:

```
public SpriteBatch batch;
```

And I instantiate it in my Create method() and pass the entire `Game` class to a `Screen` called Playscreen:

```
batch = new SpriteBatch();
setScreen(new PlayScreen(this));
```

In the constructor of PlayScreen, I set the passed `Game` class to a private field I set up:

```
this.game = game;
```

This is my entire render method for PlayScreen:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 2, 2, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);

    // Gdx.gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    game.batch.begin();
    for (Tile[] tileArray : tileMatrix.getTileMatrix())
    {
        for (Tile tile : tileArray)
        {
            tile.draw(game.batch);
        }
    }
    game.batch.end();

    hud.stage.draw();

}
```

`tileArray` is a two dimensional array that contains `Tiles`. In my create() method, every tile in this array is initialized and assigned a different location. Here is the base class:

```
public abstract class Tile extends Sprite
{
    protected Texture texture;
    protected String name;
    protected int movementPoints;
    protected int foodYield;
    protected int productionYield;
    protected int tradeYield;

    public Tile(int mP, int fY, int pY, int tY, String name, Texture texture)
    {
        this.movementPoints = mP;
        this.foodYield = fY;
        this.productionYield = pY;
        this.tradeYield = tY;
        this.name = name;
        this.texture = texture;

        setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
```

When DesktopLauncher.java is run, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.flush(SpriteBatch.java:962)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.end(SpriteBatch.java:183)
    at com.marcusorciuch.reciv.screens.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:108)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.marcusorciuch.reciv.ReCivMain.render(ReCivMain.java:47)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

@

```
game.batch.end();
```

Yeah, I don't know whats going on.

**Edit:** To those who are having this problem, make sure if you have a class that extends from `Sprite`, make sure you call `super(texture)` or else the `Sprite` parts of your class will not be instantiated.

Comment: The `texture` in all your Tiles seems to be null.

Comment: @Tenfour04 http://pastebin.com/eteh7Vrn I have instantiated the Textures in Tiles, in a child class.

Comment: why don't u want to create `SpriteBatch` as a private field directly in `PlayScreen` class?

Comment: @Enigo This doesn't work, as I've tried this already.

Comment: @MarcusOrciuch on `SpriteBatch.java:962` there is `lastTexture.bind();`.  So, as Tenfour04 said the texture seems to be null. try to sout textures of each members of `tileArray`. Also, I see you have `draw` method in tile class, share it as well.

Comment: @Enigo The 'Tile' class extends from the 'Sprite' class and my 'Tile' class does not override the 'draw' method. For the 'draw' method, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java .

Comment: @Enigo I figured it out. What I needed to do is call 'super(texture)' in order to instantiate the actual 'Sprite' part of 'Tile'. Wow that was really dumb.

Comment: :) yeah, sometimes that happens.